# How does the resistor on the LM311 comparator output work?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, comparator

This is the circuit of a GND detection probe that is a part of a PCB under production so it's supposed to be tested and it works:

[image: ground/voltage detector scheme]

The PINPROBE line is a track connected to the pin of a STM32F103xx microcontroller, configured as a digital input, reading binary values. The comparator is an [LM311D device](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/2d/22/50/0e/7e/39/43/64/CD00001072.pdf/files/CD00001072.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00001072.pdf).

What I see on this circuit is:

- Non-inverted input is a voltage divider node, in a way that Vref = 14.8V.
- The non-inverted input is viewing 18V from source supply, when Vx input is an open circuit (high impedance.) Actually there will be a little current due the BAT54 leakage current, but the non-inverted will still viewing values very close to 18V.
- The non-inverted input is connected to any load, it will see a voltage divider that will depend on the load connected (resistor and voltage values.)
- If values close to GND are connected to the pin probe (Vx node) the voltage divider will result in 9V at non-inverted input.
- The comparator output has a resistor connected to 3.3V to pull this line up as a kind of "conversion" configuration (I don't know if it is the real intention but I guess this.)

When the comparison between reference and input makes the comparator output be 0V, PINPROBE line will also put 0V on microcontroller GPIO pin. What happens when the comparaison makes thecomparator output be 18V on this line? I don't see how Rpull up is helping to convert 18V to 3.3V.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The LM311 comparator has an uncommitted output as per this image on the [TI website](https://www.ti.com/product/LM311): -

[image]

My additions are shown in magenta. In effect, COL OUT (the collector output) can be tied via a resistor to any supply rail you choose. It's not like an op-amp where the output can rise close to the full upper power rail. If using the collector as output, it is usual to tie EMIT OUT pin to ground or the negative rail pin of the device. But you can also use the emitter as an output too.

Answer (score 8):

There are three common output configurations for comparators:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0uM0k.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The "push-pull" style output (used by the [MAX903](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/609/MAX900_MAX903-3131333.pdf), for example), shown left, uses two transistors to connect the output pin either to \$V_{CC}\$ or \$V_{EE}\$, and the user has no choice over what potentials can appear there, except in their choice of supply voltages.

The third style, on the right, is called "open collector", and uses a single transistor. Many comparators, such as the [LM393](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm393.pdf), employ this technique. That transistor's emitter is tied to the negative supply, and when the transistor is switched on, the output is effectively connected directly to \$V_{EE}\$, and adopts that potential.

When the transistor is switched off, though, the output is completely isolated from anything inside the IC, including \$V_{CC}\$. That means the IC's positive supply cannot influence output potential. It's up to you to decide, in that condition, how the potential of that output should be set, and most commonly a resistance between OUT and \$V_{CC}\$ is used to gently coerce output potential to \$V_{CC}\$. The "pull-up" resistor in your design is doing something similar; setting output potential to +3.3V (instead of +18V) in the absence of the IC's internal transistor tying it to ground.

The LM311 output is actually pictured above in the middle. Like the open-collector design, there's a single transistor, but that transistor's emitter is also unconnected. In your design, that emitter (IC pin 1) is tied to ground, making it behave exactly like the open collector design. However, you could configure the transistor as an emitter follower, if you wished. The LM311 is a little more flexible in this respect, but your design is employing  the usual grounded emitter, open-collector setup.

Answer (score 5):

Rpullup isn't converting 18 volts to 3.3 volts. 18 volts is the rail voltage for the comparator. The comparator has an open-collector output and therefore can be pulled up to any voltage during the high state (Vin+ > Vin-.)

Comment: Resistor doesn't convert voltage by its own. I meant that when you have R pull up plus 3.3V you get 3.3V. My confussion was that I thought that comparators worked putting VCC+ rail voltage when the result of the comparison is '1' and they put VCC- rail voltage to its output when comparison result is '0'. This case, Vcc- = GND, and Vcc+ = 18V. Thank you very much @MOSFET, for your correction. Now it has got a lot of sense.

Comment: @Suvi_Eu you have to look at the output stage to know if the pull-up trick is going to work. What you are saying is correct but only when the output is push-pull/totem pole.

Comment: I'm on the way looking that. I'm trying to think if it is going to work. If I trust designer, it should work. But I need to understand it and to see it by my eyes, too.